# Can I modify this script to work with multiple DIV tags?

Tags: dynamic

Here is my current code:

```
var text = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
    i = 0,
    $div = $('#myDiv');

setInterval(function ()
{
    $div.fadeOut(function ()
    {
        $div.text(text[i++ % text.length]).fadeIn();
    });
}, 1000);
```

Can someone show me how to make it work with multiple DIV tags on the same page?  Right now it only works with one.

Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but maybe something like:

```
//get all the div elements with the given classname
divs = document.getElementsByClassName("myDivClassName");

//for each div, apply the update on a timer
setInterval(function () {
    for (var index = 0; index < divs.length; index++) {
        var div = divs[index];
        div.fadeOut(function () {
            div.text(text[i % text.length]).fadeIn();
        });
    }
    i++;
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery.each and/or a selector (I assume you use jQuery?)

**jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )**
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

> A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via their named properties.

**Selectors**
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

> Allows you to select elements mathing a specific jQuery selector. You can find a list of possible selectors on the jQuery selectors documentation page.

Comment: I think you should be able to use $(.myDivs).each( $(this).fadeOut(...) ) in your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var text = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
   i = 0,
   $divs = $('#DIV1, #DIV2');// or $('div.class1') for all divs
                             // with class='class1'

   setInterval(function ()
   {
       $divs.fadeOut(function (){
                        $(this).text(text[i++ % text.length]).fadeIn();
                    });
   }, 1000);

</script>
```